# Google sheet showing formula instead of evaluated result

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

Thanks for looking into this

I have an App script custom function as below which return a formula for a cell. When I use this function from a cell in google sheet it shows the formula =Sum(1,2) instead of the evaluated result i.e 3.

```
function testReturningFormula(){
 return "=Sum(1,2)"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set a cell with formula `=testReturningFormula()`, it cannot overwrite the cell's formula you've created. It can only return a string or array. You should have the formula itself parse the arguments you wish.

This should help:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions

Answer (score 0):

The custom function is not returning a formula, it's returning a string.

It's not possible to use a custom function to return a formula, they only are able to return values. Reference https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions